# why do options not affect showOpenDialog?

Tags: javascript, electron

This is the script for my renderer page:

```js
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;

function openJsonFile() {
  dialog.showOpenDialog(
  {
    title: 'Open JSON file',
    properties: ['openFile'],
    filters: [{name: 'JSON', extensions: 'json'}]
  },
  
  function (filename) {
    ....
    ....
    ....
  })
};
```

But the options don't affect showOpenDialog at all. It's the same as with default options. Why is that and how to fix that?

P.S. I'm using mac

Answer (score 0):

`showOpenDialog` function takes two parameters. First is `browserWindow(optional)` and 2nd is `options`. You are passing options as 1st parameter.

[Here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options) is the detailed explanation of this.